# Prevent high cost for google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, rate-limiting

I’m working on a small app that invokes a Google cloud function without authentication (no sign in).
I am wondering how can I protect my function from being invoked too many times (in order to prevent high cost due to pricing per invocation).
Is there a way to rate limit spamming ips or to shut the entire function down if it reaches a certain invocation count?

Thanks!

Comment: Store the count in a db, read this value from the db, if it exceeds your specified limit don't call the function.

Comment: But In order to read from the db I need the function to be invoked and that is what I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: This is something you will have to implement yourself if you don't want one of the other ways provided by that platform to limit invocations or costs. It is non-trivial to implement, and there is no provided tool for this.  The platform will *always* attempt to invoke your function when requested, and you will pay for that invocation no matter what the function does. The best you can do is set up a [budget alert](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) and shut down the function yourself if you think it's going to cost too much.

Comment: 1/2) The key in your post is `without authentication`. If you do not require authorization, then anything can access your endpoint. One option is to limit the number of instances of your function. Review this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--max-instances). However, the best solution is to implement authorization. IAP then validates the HTTP authorization header and blocks all traffic that fails. Your function will never be invoked for failed authorization.

Comment: 2/2) Other possibilities include creating an HTTP load balancer, Cloud Armor, and a NEG for your function. That is a heavyweight solution with additional costs. In summary, a public function is public and there is a cost for enabling that feature.